# "mountall: event failed" after a reboot causes system to become unbootable

Tags: 10.04, boot, mount, boot-failure

My server crashed today and upon rebooting gives the following error message and will not boot:

```
mounted-tmp main process (700) terminated with status 127
mountall: event failed
```

and then hangs.

I am able to boot into the recovery console but when trying to select the device for root file system I find it only at: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root` none of the other devices `/dev/sda1-6` work.

If I use `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root` I get a shell and can see my files but can't do much else.  Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!